# upload a file to server without reload of my page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, iframe, file-upload

Ok,this is tricky.

- I have a form which ask user to upload a file.
- I am **not** submitting the form on **submit** button,I am doing it on click of an image enclosed in `href="#"`
- reloading the page is to be avoided.(this is the most challenging part)

I have used prevent default on href click and then sended an ajax call to my php page.This does not work.

*If I use a  tag..it reloads.
If I dont use it,i cant send my file.
I can only use multipart form data when using form tag.*

**What do i do??**
iframe,upclick.js..but i am totally unaware of these.

Just in case if you want to go through my code(note:not a working model,just wanted to keep the question clean):http://jsfiddle.net/feRx3/

Hope I am clear with my question.

A little embarrassing at 1200 rep,I fumble at form.Any help?IE7 support is must!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have used [jQuery form plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/). It uses ajax 2.0 if you are on a modern browser or falls back to an iFrame for old browsers.

Answer (score -1):

You should not reinvent the wheel. There are plenty of libraries that does the job.

Try Plupload : http://www.plupload.com/

Comment: If the browser support one of these technologies : Flash, Silverlight, Gears, BrowserPlus or HTML5, it will be ok.

Comment: Not sure. But there are plenty of libraries like plupload that specify that they are IE6 ready : http://www.enfew.com/12-excellent-ajax-upload-plugins/